# jQuery click event handler not working in IE although functions in event handler operate correctly

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, event-handling, jquery-events

ASP.NET MVC application.

Only IE has the problem.

Consider these 2 functions:

```
function refreshParameters() {
                doRefresh('#loading-production-parameters', '#partial-rows-parameters', '@VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/home/ProductionParameters")');
            }
            //
            //
            //
function refreshTotals() {
                doRefresh('#loading-production-totals', '#partial-rows-totals', '@VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/home/ProductionTotals")');
            }
```

Beginning of script and event handler:

```
$(function () {
            //
            //Init
            //Initial Tasks
            //
            refreshParameters();
            refreshTotals();
            //
            // Events
            //
            $('#yla-debug').click(function (e) {
                refreshParameters();
                refreshTotals();
            });
```

The strange thing is that `refreshParameters` and `refreshTotals` run when the page loads.

But on the click event handler they don't.

If I put an alert in the event handler it fires up ok, also console in firebug shows no errors.

Any ideas?

P.S.: the html markup for the element that uses the event:

```
<div id="yla-debug" class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
        <h3 class="panel-title pull-left">Daily Production Data for <span style="font-weight: bold;">@ViewBag.SiteName</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</h3>
        <span style="font-weight: normal; background-color: #000080;" class="badge pull-left">(Autoupdate every 30 min.)</span>
        <div class="pull-right" id="loading-production-parameters">
            <span>Refreshing</span>
            <img src="~/Content/ajax-loader-bar1.gif" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <table id="partial-rows-parameters" class="table table-striped table-hover">
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
            <span>Last Refresh: </span>
            <span id="last_refresh_parameters"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**ADDITIONAL INFO #1:**

Even if I replace the selector to a more generic one it doesn't work. `$('body), $('img')` ....

**ADDITIONAL INFO #2:**

The `doRefresh` method which does not run when called from event but runs on startup:

```
function doRefresh(what, dataContainer, action) {
                $(what).show();
                $.ajax({
                    url: action,
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $(dataContainer).html(data);
                        $(what).hide();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Try alerting $('#yla-debug').length to be sure that the selector is fetching the required dom elements. Also try to attach a debugger inside the click function to check if the control actually ends up there..

Comment: How can this happen, i mean the funcitons run ok at the start..and the click handler works with the alert...

Answer (score 0):

Just my stupidity...

This solves my problems:

```
$.ajaxSetup({                
               cache: false 
            });
```

IE does many things differently, so does in caching AJAX requests.